# Политика сбора данных к 1 июля

Tags: юридические-аспекты

С 1 июля 2017 идет ужесточение в закон о сборе персональных данных. Варианты действий в Интернете озвучиваются такие:

- разместить под формой политику конфиденциальности,
- добавить еще и чекбокс для согласия,
- делать pop-up или редирект при отправке формы с раскрытием уведомления о сборе данных
- регистрация в роспремнадрозе как оператора сбора данных.

Подскажите где здесь суть, а где уже перебор? Так как добавить то не сложно, а вот на конверсию это может очень негативно сказаться.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию.

Comment: @Kromster жаль, а я бы почитал. А еще ответ про подобный закон на счет онлайн продажи и отправки отчета в налоговую. тоже с 1 июля начнётся жесть..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я бы тоже почитал. И много чего другого - как бетон разводить, как мясо мариновать, устройство форсунок, кто такие интроверты.. и т.д.

Comment: @Kromster но вопрос о сборе и хранении перс. данных, так или иначе, относится к разработке и важно знать при разработке приложений, сайтов, магазинов и пр - что и как стоит с этим делать.  Разве нет? В отличии от перечисления выше..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский к разработке относятся примерно так же как и другие оффтопные темы. Здесь нужен толковый юрист, а не разработчик. По крайней мере мой голос за закрытие основан на этом. За Ника и двух + на моем комментарии не скажу. Если более конструктивно - стоит поднять вопрос на Мете.